# Counterexample on the limit of $\frac{f(x)}{x}$

Tags: examples-counterexamples

Is the following statement true or false?

$f$ is defined on the set of all real numbers, such that $\lim \limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac{f(x)}{x}$ is a real number $L$ and $f(0)=0$.
Then $L=0$?

I can't draw up any counterexample.

Would be grateful for hint.

Comment: You can't daw up $f(x)=x$?

Comment: Ohh yes. I have mistaken during the test.

Answer (score 2):

Simply set $f(x)=x$. Then $L=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $f=\sinh(x)$ while $L=1$ and $f(0)=0$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Simply  let $f(x)=x^2+x$

Answer (score 1):

Infact $L$ can be any real number because $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin ax}x=a$$